# comment about her s* anatomy

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand "comment about her sexual anatomy" as "comment about her based on her gender (it is apparently of sex discrimination)" Am I on the right track?

> That same week on Twitter, the neuroscientist also lashed out at Rasmussen, who has tried to explain studies suggesting a natural origin of SARS-CoV-2 to the public. He called her fat, and then posted a derogatory **comment about her sexual anatomy**. Rasmussen says, “This debate has moved so far from the evidence that I don’t know if we can dial it back.”

Source: [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01383-3)

Comment: I would understand it to mean "a derogatory comment mentioning her 'private parts'" (making it doubly rude).

Comment: If so, the "commentor" was a loser then, not well-intentioned.

Comment: You don't need to understand "sexual anatomy" to know that the "commentor"  was ***hostile*** - that aspect is made clear by the word ***derogatory***. But any dictionary will define ***sexual*** and ***anatomy***, so I think this is essentially General Reference.

Comment: Note the word "sexual" is not itself an offensive or taboo word.  There is no need to write it as "S*" in the title.  Indeed the use of the phrase "sexual anatomy" is done to avoid using any potentially offensive words.

Comment: comment on her sexual anatomy, on his sexual anatomy, on their sexual anatomy. [commentor is not a word in English.]

Comment: @Lambie: No. I coined the word "commetor" and put it in quotation marks to highlight the novel use.

Comment: It appears that Ms Rasmussen said that the letter he wrote to _Science_ may have been well-intentioned - certainly not his tweet attacking her personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is showing gender discrimination. But that information is not in the language that is present here. It is from the context of the society that this text comes from.

Someone who knows English well, but doesn't know about the society that this text comes from, might not see the gender discrimination.

The point of the text here is just that a "derogatory comment about her sexual anatomy" is far away from science and evidence about SARS-CoV-2.

Answer (score 2):

It's worse than that. It implies he made a criticising remark about her breasts. (Or possibly even genitals, but that's unlikely.)

Comment: It is perfectly possible to make insulting remarks about women's genitals.